# Why am I getting a syntax error at the gt

Tags: python

```
n1 = int(input("Enter first number :"))
 
n2 = int(input("Enter second number :"))
 
if n1 &gt;= n2 :
print("n1 is the biggest ", n1)
 
else:
print('n2 is biggest',n2)
```

Comment: What error you got from python Interpreter?

Comment: I would suggest using a different tutorial website; it looks like this one has some issues causing characters to print improperly, which might potentially cause problems in other code samples they offer.

Answer (score 4):

The code you’ve posted is simply not valid Python. You probably copied it from a website that has some erroneous markup, and the `&gt;` part is meant to read `>`:

```
n1 = int(input("Enter first number :"))
n2 = int(input("Enter second number :"))

if n1 >= n2:
    print("n1 is the biggest ", n1)
else:
    print('n2 is biggest', n2)
```

**Pay attention to indentation**, it’s *important* in Python.

Comment: not too good an answer. print()  if  ...  else print() .The indent is not wrong rather it's a syntax error or ternary has to be used

Comment: @VisheshMangla What do you mean? The indentation in the original code is *definitely* wrong. The fact that there are better ways of writing this is undisputed; but I prefer not confusing OP even more. For now, this is the code they’re working with.

Comment: @VisheshMangla A ternary should *not* be used here. As an expression, the conditional ("ternary") operator serves to produce a value, which neither of the branches does.

Comment: sorry, before editing it seemed that they were writing the print in the same line as if

Comment: I know that @MisterMiyagi, I was just talking what is syntactically correct